# How to reset Oracle user password when you can't login

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I forgot my username and password at all so i cannot create any new connection, also i don't have any connection at all. I already uninstalled it and installed it again. Because people said that in the installation process we will be setting the username and password. But it does not show at all. Is there any solution for this?  my Version 19.4.0.354

Comment: SQL Developer is a client which requires username and password in the connection to connect to a database. Even if you reinstall the client, you will still require to setup a new connection and provide all the required details.

Comment: i know, the thing is i completely forgot it and i could not find anyway to access the username and password i forgot in order to reset them or anyway and i did not know that reinstalling is still keeping the username and the password from previous installation before the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the **database** you're connecting to. SQL Developer is just a tool, it doesn't require any credentials itself.

If you don't know users nor their passwords, ask your DBA to provide/reset them for you. Or, if the database is installed on your PC, then you're the DBA. Login to operating system as the owner of Oracle software (on MS Windows, that's probably "Administrator"). Open command prompt window and run

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Then see which users you have:

```
select * From all_users;
```

Reset any password by e.g.

```
alter user potato identified by student;
```

Then go back to SQL Developer and provide these credentials while establishing connection.

If you're unsure of how the database name is, check TNSNAMES.ORA file; you'll use database's alias found in that file. For example, if it is an Express Edition, it is most probably "XE".